# How do I filter by category in chrome's about://tracing | catapult tracing project?

Tags: trace

In the chrome tracing format specification, https://docs.google.com/document/d/1CvAClvFfyA5R-PhYUmn5OOQtYMH4h6I0nSsKchNAySU/edit, there is optional category information for filtering. How do I even access that filtering in chrome's about://tracing; that is catapult's tracing: https://github.com/catapult-project/catapult/tree/master/tracing